# Getting address with MemorySharp

Tags: c#, memory-management

I'm using MemorySharp to calculate the memory address from a pointer address and then inject values in memory.

The code works perfectly, but I was wondering if this would be the right way. I found a little dirty the way I'm calculating the memory address. Maybe there's a easier way that I'm not able to see.

Any advice, memory related, or clean code, etc.. is welcome.

````
class Amongus {

   private const string nameGame = "Among Us";
   private const int addrM = 0x01D4358C;
   private MemorySharp mSharp = new MemorySharp(Process.GetProcessesByName(nameGame).FirstOrDefault());

   // Static Address
   readonly List<int> moveSpeedOffset = new List<int> { 0x4, 0x74 };

   public Amongus()  { }

   // Calculate Address.
   private IntPtr getAddress(int baseM, List<int> offsets)
   {
      try
      {
         IntPtr Base_ptr = mSharp["GameAssembly.dll"].BaseAddress + baseM;
         IntPtr Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base_ptr, false);

         int count = 0;
         foreach (int ptr in offsets)
         {
            if (count != offsets.Count - 1)
            {
               Base += ptr;
               Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base, false);
               count++;
            }
            else { Base += ptr; }
          }

          return Base;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
         return new IntPtr(0);
      } 
  }

public void changeMoveSpeed2(float speed) => mSharp[getAddress(addrM, moveSpeedOffset), false].Write(speed);

}
```
````

Comment: In 64 bit app the address is `long` not `int`, check `IntPtr.Size`.

Comment: @aepot Hello once again! I tried changing `addrM` type to long type, the thing is that I can't sum the IntPtr that returns the `BaseAddress` with a long type. I saw that Microsoft docs has `LongPtr` type ([here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type)), but when I try to declare it, it doesn't recognize it as a type

Comment: I'm not about `IntPtr`, it's always ok on any platform. You misunderstood me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean code advice.
You need to calculate Base in a loop with two expressions:

```
Base += ptr;
Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base, false);
```

The second should not be calculated for the last iteration, but before the loop you have

```
IntPtr Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base_ptr, false);
```

So, mSharp.Read should be executed before adding ptr, right? Let's do so:

```
IntPtr Base_ptr = mSharp["GameAssembly.dll"].BaseAddress + baseM;
IntPtr Base = Base_ptr;

foreach (int ptr in offsets)
{
    Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base, false);
    Base += ptr;
}
```

Now we don't need count variable. The Base_ptr is excessive, and we can calculate loop in one expression:

```
IntPtr Base = mSharp["GameAssembly.dll"].BaseAddress + baseM;
foreach (int ptr in offsets)
    Base = mSharp.Read<IntPtr>(Base, false) + ptr;
```

which makes a perfect sense to me.

And you probably want to return IntPtr.Zero, not new IntPtr(0), in the case of exception.

Comment: It makes sense, I don't know how I didn't think in that. Thanks a lot for that clean code advice!